# Add users with Active Directory email attribute to a group which contains "@abc.com"

Tags: powershell, email, scripting, automation, active-directory

We have the ticketing system to create Window ID for the new joiner, we need to add the new user to a specific grouping depends on their email domain.

For example if the user's e-mail address is `thomas@abc.com`, it will check if the email address contains `@abc.com`, then add it to the `test_group`; if the user in the group, skip this step.

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties emailaddress

foreach ($user in $Users)
{
    if ($user.emailaddress -match "abc.com") 
    {
            $GroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "test_group" | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
            if ($User.SamAccountName -NotIn $GroupMembers)
            {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "test_group" -Members $User
            }
        }
    }
```

But after I execute, I got hit error as below

> You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
>   At line:9 char:42
>
> Unexpected token 'NotIn' in expression or statement.
>   At line:9 char:43
>
> Unexpected token 'GroupMembers' in expression or statement.
>   At line:9 char:49

Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell do you use?

Comment: PSVersion  2.0 @wp78de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use the `-NotIn` comparison operator in your code.
However, this operator was only [introduced in PowerShell 3](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell3-notin.htm) and wont work with your version of PoSh.

You can use [`-NotContains`](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_contains.htm#Example_5:_PowerShell_-NotContains) in PowerShell v2.x and up. However, you will need reverse your check. Using -NotIn you are comparing a value to a collection, with `-NotContains` you do the reverse by comparing a collection to a value.